# Drawing arrows and coloring fields with a flipped board is broken

Tags: bug, pgn-viewer

Normal orientation works:

```
[FEN ""]
[StartPly "2"]

1. e4 {[%draw arrow,e2,e4,red][%draw full,e1,green]}
```

Flipping sides doesn't move the drawings:

```
[FEN ""]
[Startflipped "1"]
[StartPly "2"]

1. e4 {[%draw arrow,e2,e4,red][%draw full,e1,green]}
```

Tested in Microsoft Edge 104.0.1293.54 and Firefox 103.0.2.

Comment: ... I've been using the PGN viewer for six years, but this feature is completely new to me :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a bug.